# Add 2 list of lists with different lengths

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have 2 lists.
List 1 (say X) is =

```
[ 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ]
```

List 2 is a list (Say Y) of list which will always have row size in multiples of 4 BUT the row sizes may not be same.

eg -

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] , [1,2,3,4]]
```

I want to find column-wise sum of elements in groups of 4

So for this example the sums will be [2,4,6,8] [5,6,7,8]

Currently, I am using 
`X = [sum(e) for e in zip(X , Y[j][count:count+4])]`

Where count is fixed for one complete traversal of columns. So say the number of columns in Y are 200. So for each traversal for groups of 4 numbers, count will stay same (it is used to slice the matrix)

But as soon as the row length changes for the last 4 elements, X becomes empty.
Where count is incremented as soon as Y gets fully traversed column-wise.

Please ask for any further details. I can also provide a minimal reproducible example if needed in the form of a text file containing the matrix and the code I am currently using.

Comment: I don't get the logic

Comment: How is X related to Y? To sum every four elements is ok, but what is expected to do with each 4 Y elements sum?

Comment: I wanted to calculate mean of column-wise sum of 4 elements. So the sums in X will be divided by the number of times they occur

Comment: @U10-Forward what do you not understand please comment, ill edit the question and add the details

Comment: @TanmayBhatnagar "what do you not understand" everything.

Comment: You want to Sum each 4 values in Y and map them into X[index] values? Try to simplify what you want your algorithm to do. it seems like you are giving a few details that are not important to your programming problem, and you are not giving any hints at all about what you want to do with X and Y

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure how everything fits together in your question, but for the "zipping lists with different length" problem you can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with `fillvalue=0`. You could then subdivide the resulting list of sums into chunks in a second step.

```
>>> lsts = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] , [1,2,3,4]]                                 
>>> from itertools import zip_longest                                      
>>> sums = [sum(x) for x in zip_longest(*lsts, fillvalue=0)]               
>>> [sums[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(sums), 4)]                          
[[2, 4, 6, 8], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: @U10-Forward Well, zip the lists, add elements in the same places, and (maybe) group by sets of four elements. How do you understand it?

Answer (score 0):

Using `grouper` is another approach:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

y = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] , [1,2,3,4]]

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)


[[sum(t) for t in l] for l in grouper(zip_longest(*y, fillvalue=0), 4)]
```

Output:

```
[[2, 4, 6, 8], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Not so optimized solution :**

```
y = [
     [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
     [1,2,3,4],
     [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13]
     ]

#  Statge-1 get the max column length 
max_cols = len(max(*y))

#  Stage-2 if any of them is having the cols less than max_cols, 
#  then fill with 0
word_list1 = [i if len(i) == max_cols else i+[0]*(max_cols-len(i)) for i in y]

#  Stage-3 sum the elements of corresponding columns
sum_the_list = [sum(x) for x in zip(*word_list1)]   
# or list(numpy.sum(word_list1, 0)) 

#  Stage-4 if required create the sub-lists 
sum_the_list1 = [sum_the_list[l:l+4] for l in range(0, max_cols, 4)]

#### Output ####

Stage1
 [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13]
 ]

Stage2
 [3, 6, 9, 12, 10, 12, 14, 16, 10, 11, 12, 13]

Stage3
 [
  [3, 6, 9, 12],
  [10, 12, 14, 16],
  [10, 11, 12, 13]
  ]
```